# integration of $ \int_0^{+∞} \operatorname{sech}^2(x)e^{ux}dx$?

Tags: integration

$\def\sech{\operatorname{sech}}$

Please can anyone help me to take the integration of $$\int_0^{+\infty}\sech^2(x)e^{ux}dx$$ and $$\int_0^{+\infty}\cosh(x)e^{ux}dx$$

where $\sech(x)$ and $\cosh(x)$ are defined as hyperbolic secant and cosine functions, $e^{ux}$ is the exponential function,and $u$ is a constant.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Any insights on how to solve this?

Comment: @Masacroso. I typed my naswer since the first edit of your comment was (at least to me - I am almost blind) almost impossible to read. Cheers and Merry Xmas.

Answer (score 3):

For the second one, we let $u=-s$

$$\begin{align}I&=\int_0^\infty e^{ux}\cosh x\,\mathrm dx\\&=\int_0^\infty e^{-sx}\cosh x\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}\cosh t\,\mathrm dt\\&=\mathcal{L}(\cosh t)\\&=\dfrac{s}{s^2-a^2},\text{where }s=-u, \text{ and }a=1\\&=\dfrac{-u}{u^2-1}\\&=\dfrac{u}{1-u^2}\end{align}$$

Comment: OFF TOPIC : After Quora, its Math.SE is it? :p

Comment: @Pragyadita Das, old habits die hard ;)

Answer (score 2):

For the second integral

$$ \int_0^\infty e^{ux}\cdot \frac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2} dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty (e^{(u+1)x} + e^{(u-1)x})\ dx = \frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{e^{(u+1)x}}{u+1} + \frac{e^{(u-1)x}}{u-1} \right]_0^\infty $$

This only converges for $\Re(u) < -1$ and the answer is
$$ -\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{u+1} + \frac{1}{u-1} \right) = -\frac{u}{u^2-1} $$

---

For the first integral
$$ \begin{align} 
\int_0^\infty \frac{4e^{ux}}{(e^x + e^{-x})^2} dx &=4 \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ux}e^{-2x}}{(1+e^{-2x})^2}dx \\
&= 2\int_0^1 \frac{t^{-u/2}}{(1+t)^2} dt & (t=e^{-2x}) \\
&= 2\int_0^1 t^{-u/2}\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)(-1)^kt^k\right) dt \\
&= 2\sum_{k=1}^\infty (k+1)(-1)^k \int_0^1 t^{k-u/2} dt \\
&= 2\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{k+1}{k-u/2} \\
\end{align} $$

This converges for $\Re(u)<2$

Answer (score 2):

For the sech integral, assume $u<0$. Then integration by parts gives
$$-u\int_0^\infty\tanh x\, e^{ux}\,dx.$$
Now
$$\tanh x=\frac{1-e^{-2x}}{1+e^{-2x}}
=1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^ne^{-2nx}.$$
Therefore
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\tanh x\, e^{ux}\,dx
&=\int_0^\infty e^{ux}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\int_0^\infty e^{-(2n-u)x}\,dx\\
&=-\frac1u+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2n-u}.
\end{align}
The original integral equals
$$1-2u\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2n-u}.$$
If one likes one can express this in terms of the digamma function
$$\frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)}
=-\gamma+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n-1+z}\right).$$

Comment: one question: how you justify the swap of the summation and the integral?

Comment: @Masacroso Apply monotone convergence ... but not to the whole series!

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\sech}{\operatorname{sech}}$As Masacroso typed in a comment, a CAS gives
$$\int_0^{+\infty}\sech^2(x)e^{ux}\,dx=1+\frac{1}{2} u \left(H_{-\frac{u}{4}}-H_{-\frac{u}{4}-\frac{1}{2}}\right)$$ where appears harmonic numbers (the formule is valid if $\Re(u)<2$.

For the antiderivative,
$$(u+2)e^{-ux}\int\sech^2(x)e^{ux}\,dx$$ is given by $$(u+2) \, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{u}{2};\frac{u+2}{2};-e^{2 x}\right)-u e^{2 x} \,
   _2F_1\left(1,\frac{u+2}{2};\frac{u+4}{2};-e^{2 x}\right)+(u+2) \tanh (x)$$
The second one is simple.

Comment: at your level you are supposed to give more clues and context than horrible special functions gotten from a cas

Comment: @reuns. Be sure I tried but I gave up and "blindly" used a CAS.

Comment: I said so because $\sum_{m=1}^\infty (-1)^m (\frac{m}{u+2+2m}-\frac{m}{2+2m})$ appears which should be related to $u \frac{\Gamma'(u/2+1)}{\Gamma(u/2+1)}$